# Why does Array Overflow return a 0 here?

Tags: arrays, c, overflow

```
#include <stdio.h>

void ModifyArray(int *ptr1, int *ptr2, int *ptr3) {
   for(int i = 0; i<4; i++) {
      ptr3[i] = ptr1[i+0] - ptr2[i+3];
   }
}

int main() {

   int Array1[6];
   int Array2[6];
   int Array3[6];

   ModifyArray(&Array1[0], &Array2[0], &Array3[0]);

   printf("%d\n", Array2[6]);

   return 0;
}
```

While experimenting with undefined Array behavior I have noticed that when I use the function `ModifyArray(&Array1[0], &Array2[0], &Array3[0]);` and go over the bounds of `Array2`, `Array2[6]` always returns `0`. When I remove the function, `Array2[6]` returns a random number, as expected. Why does creating the function `ModifyArray` cause `Array2[6]` to go from undefined behavior to `0`?

Comment: *"Why does calling the function ModifyArray cause Array2[6] to go from undefined behavior to 0?"* - it doesn't. That's how it managed to manifest in your environment. It's still *undefined* behavior, and may render entirely different artifacts in other (or the same) environment(s). Thus the nature of *undefined*; there is no formal definition of behavior.

Comment: But why does it always return 0, no matter how often i run the code? Shouldnt it return a different value with each run? When I dont use the function, it returns different numbers with each run of the code. After I use the function, it doesnt matter if I remove it after, Array2[6] always returns 0.

Comment: That behaviour is included in the set of [undefined behaviour]

Answer (score 0):

> *Why does creating the function `ModifyArray` cause `Array2[6]` to go from undefined behavior to `0`?*

Well, the value `0`, or any value, for that matter is result of [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Just because the value is 0, does not mean this is well-defined behaviour. It is **still** undefined behaviour.